# How do I slow down the timing of keyIsDown?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im trying to finetune the controls of a javascript game (p5 library).
keyIsDown() is the type of control/feel im looking for but it's timing is too fast.

By timing is too fast, I mean when I hold down the key, the key repeats too fast. Im trying to control the timing speed of the key repeat when holding down the key.

I tried to make my own vertion with keytyped() and setInterval to time my move function. Then stopping it with keyReleased(). But it jams up.

I have also tried setTimeout but could not get it to work on keyboard input like this.

```
var controlInterval;

function keyReleased() { 
  if (key === 'a') {
    clearInterval(controlInterval);
  } else if (key === 'd') {
    clearInterval(controlInterval);
  }
  //return false; // prevent any default behavior
}


function keyTyped() {
  if (key === 'a') {
    controlInterval = setInterval(left, 50);
  } else if (key === 'd') {
    controlInterval = setInterval(right, 50);
  }

}
function left(){
  var x = -1;
  move(x);
}

function right(){
  var x = 1;
  move(x);
}
```

code I prefer to use:

```
if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
  var west = -1;
  move(west);
}
if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
  var east = 1;
  move(east);
```

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it is hard to know what you are asking. Take a look at this sketch https://editor.p5js.org/charlie-openschool/sketches/V_emCQrgg how does its behavior differ from what you are trying to do?

Comment: Here is a similar sketch that uses keyIsDown how does this compare to what you want? https://editor.p5js.org/charlie-openschool/sketches/gmDQeYwi1 Perhaps you can use ideas from these sketches to make a runnable snippet to better show us what you want.

Comment: By timing is too fast, I mean when I hold down the key, the key repeats too fast. Im trying to control the key timing speed of the repeat when holding down the key. Lets say I want to half the speed. Now the game is grid based so I cant just half the distanse. I need to slow down the key input itself.

Comment: Instead of making the keyboard input reads slower (wich is somewhat tricky, to say the least), you could increment your variables by less than 1. Could that be a solution? Instead of `east = 1`, try `east = 0.5`. I assume that in the `move` function your are incrementing/decrementing by the value `east` the x/y of the player.

Comment: For instance how would you make your second keyIsDown sketch move at half the speed but still move one pixel at a time?

Comment: Francisco Hanna: In my code the east = 1 just indicates direction. It's grid based. So i cant move in less increments.

Comment: Just realized half the speed can be done with a simple if statement and a counter.
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
  west++;
    if (west === 2){
      move(-1);
      west = 0;
    }
  } - cant figgure out comment formatting though. lol

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `debouncing` and `throttling` principles which I think is what you are looking for here - limit the execution count of event.

The best explanation IMHO related to this subject is this [article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

[image]

There are already libraries to help you like [lodash](https://lodash.com/). Go to their documentation page and search the functions - `debounce` or `throttle` and it there will be examples how to use them.

```
someDiv.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(handleKeyUp, 300));

function handleKeyUp(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 65 /* A */) left();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best option but too advanced for me. I will try the counter method to half the speed then increase the framerate. Rather than just decrease the framerate which looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow keys can be used to signal a direction, frame rate can be used to control speed and a delta variable used to control the amount of movement.

```js
var xPos = 0;
var xDelta = 1;
function setup(){
 createCanvas(200,200);
 frameRate(10); // 10 frames per second, increase to move faster
}

function draw(){
  background(100);
  
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
    var west = -1;
    move(west);
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
    var east = 1;
    move(east);
  }

  rect(xPos, 100, 10,10);
}

function move(dir){
  if (dir == -1){
    xPos = xPos - xDelta;
  }
  else {
    xPos = xPos + xDelta;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will go with an if statement and a counter to half the speed then increase the framerate. Rather than just decrease the framerate which looks bad.